# Remove Class from all images on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have no idea from javascript and I need a little help here. From resources here and there I am trying to do the following logic.

When the browser has a width less than 700px then all images that have class "star-wars" will have that class removed.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  /*If browser resized, check width again */
  if ($(window).width() < 700) {
    function myFunction() {
      var element = document.querySelectorAll('img.has-zoom');
      element.classList.remove("has-zoom");
    }
  }
});
```

Obviously the above code is wrong. I need you to tell me how the above can be written correctly (if this is the right one).

Comment: You are declaring a `function myFunction()` (not calling it). For solve this, you must declare the `function myFunction()` outside the `$(window).resize` and call it inside `if ($(window).width() < 700) {` with `myFunction();`

Comment: There is also strange mix of jQuery and vanilla js.                                                  document.querySelectorAll returns an array which you must iterate yourslef. $("img.has-zoom").removeClass() will remove it for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `document.querySelectorAll('img.has-zoom')` will return a NodeList not an element.

You need to loop through the returned list or get the element you want from it to extract the `classList` from it.

Try :

```
window.addEventListener('resize', removeClass);

function removeClass() {
  width = window.innerWidth || $(window).width();

  if ( window.innerWidth < 700) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('img.has-zoom');
    [].forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
        el.classList.remove("has-zoom");
    });
  }
}
```

**Sample that removes class after 2 seconds:**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('img.has-zoom');
  [].forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("has-zoom");
  });
}, 2000);
```

```css
.has-zoom {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<img alt="Image 1" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a29d596b0af040d7def18d1801340a8b" class="has-zoom">
<img alt="Image 2" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a29d596b0af040d7def18d1801340a8b">
<img alt="Image 3" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a29d596b0af040d7def18d1801340a8b" class="has-zoom">
```

Comment: How do I incorporate the if browser width less than 700px here?

Comment: Check the updated code with the `resize` event listener.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using `jQuery`, here is a simple solution:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 700) {
        $(".has-zoom").removeClass("has-zoom")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct.

You can add an event listener to the window to check if it is being resized, and from there check the actual size of the screen and remove the classes where necessary.

```
<!-- images with class -->
<img class="star-wars" />
<img class="star-wars" />
<img class="star-wars" />
<img class="star-wars" />
<img class="star-wars" />

// javascript
// listen for the window being resized
window.addEventListener('resize', checkScreenSize);

// function to call every time the window is resized
function checkScreenSize() {
  // check size of window
  if ( window.innerWidth < 700) {
    // loop through images with class name attached
    var images = document.getElementsByClassName('star-wars');
    for ( var i = 0; i < images.length; i++ ) {
      // remove class from each image
      images[i].classList.remove('star-wars')
    }
  }
}
```

You can add another conditional statement to add the class back on if the window gets resized above 700px again.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, below code will remove the elements which has class 'star-wars' when the browser width is less than 700px

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 700) {
        const element = document.querySelectorAll('img.has-zoom');
        if (element.classList.contains("classToBeRemoved")) {
              element.classList.remove("classToBeRemoved");
        }
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var classNameRemoved = false;

$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 700 && !classNameRemoved) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll("img.has-zoom");
        elements.forEach(function (element) {
            element.classList.remove("has-zoom");
        });

        classNameRemoved = true;
    }
});
```